# How do I convert a JSON string to an array in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to convert this JSON string (which is inside a POST variable):

```
[["2022-11-22","fasfasf","[[\"1,2\"],[\"3,4\"],[\"5\"]]"]]
```

to an array, such that:

```
arr[0] = "2022-11-22"
arr[1] = "fasfasf"
arr[2] = "[["1,2"],["3,4"],["5"]]"
```

I've tried decoding the json string in this manner:

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));
foreach($data as $d){
    $data1 = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($d)));
    echo $data1[0].','.$data1[1].','.$data1[2];
}
```

Upon executing the code, I keep getting the error:

`foreach() argument must be of type array|object...`

How do I proceed?

Comment: I'd first try and figure out why there are slashes in there. Where is that JSON coming from?

Comment: I am using `stripslashes` to remove those slashes. So, it should work. I am sending the JSON from javascript

Comment: It looks like the last value is itself json encoded, so remove the stripslashes

Comment: I think the issue is that your JSON isn't valid so json_decode returns `null`. If you're in control of creating/posting the JSON then I'd start there and get it to post valid JSON. I can't see all the details yet, but this looks like an XY problem maybe.

Comment: > "I am using stripslashes..." my point is that you shouldn't have to. I think the issue is on the frontend. It should be posting valid JSON.

Comment: Is it valid JSON? Try finding the error, it could have hidden ASCII characters. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of minutes of struggling, I finally found the solution. I had forgotten to parse the JSON string into an actual array. The following code did the trick:

```
var jsonstr = '[[\"1,2\"],[\"3,4\"],[\"5\"]]';
var jsonarr = JSON.parse(jsonstr);

//then send this jsonarr to the server using JSON.stringify()
```